# Placing red,black balls in n places

Tags: permutation, combinations

There are `n` places and **there are unlimited number of black balls and red balls with black balls numbered from 1 to c1 and red balls numbered from 1 to c2**.The question is to find the total number of ways of placing these balls in n places such that if red ball is placed then it must be followed by a black ball.**It means that the place next to red ball has to be filled by a black ball.**

`c1+c2>n`. Only one ball can be placed in one place.

**My approach**:First calculate the total number of ways to place these balls in n places,this is equal to `(c1+c2)^n` .And then subtracting from it the total number of placing two red balls together,this is equal to `2! x (c1+c2)^(n-2)`. I am not very sure if my approach is correct.Please help.

Comment: This would be a better question on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: But a black ball can have another black ball next to it?

Comment: Yes, a black ball can have a black ball next to it.

Comment: can the place next to red ball be empty? (if n < c1 + c2)

Comment: @icepack:None of the places can be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Total number of permutations is (c<sub>1</sub>+c<sub>2</sub>)!. Invalid options are those with 2 adjacent red balls.

Let's choose 2 adjacent places: 
[image]
and choose 2 red balls to fill:[image]

Subtract the invalid options from total possibilities range:[image]

After some simplifications we get [image]

Comment: Total number of permutations is not (c1+c2)! .There can be two adjacent black balls with the same number.

Comment: @g4ur4v You're contradicting yourself. You wrote: "*there are c1 number of black balls with each numbered from 1 to c1*"